# Adding target to UIButton does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift3

I'm new to iOS programming and am following the Apple 'Start Developing' course to get to know how iOS app development works. I'm at the point of adding a view to my storyboard. This new view contains a button which I create programmatically.

The app layout, the highlighted part is the added view.

[image: App layout, highlighted part is the view]

I'm trying to add an action to this button but it just won't work.

My code in `RatingControl.swift`:

```
// MARK: Button Action
func ratingButtonTapped(button: UIButton) {
    print("Button pressed")
}

// MARK: Initialization
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    addSubview(button)
}
```

Now my screen when I run the app:

[image: running screen]

Clicking the red square doesn't print anything in the output window. I also added a breakpoint in the action function but it never breaks.

Comment: @rmaddy If it isn't being called, how do you account for the visible red square in exactly the right spot?

Comment: One problem is that this is not how you make a button in code: `UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))`. You call `UIButton(type:)`.

Comment: @matt I account for it by admitting a total failure in reading the code completely. :)

Comment: @matt I changed the code. See changes in post

Comment: I don't see any change. - My guess is that the problem is that Rating Control does not have its "user interaction enabled" set to `true` (i.e. checked).

Comment: @matt small code change in the initialization of the `UIButton`. User interaction enabled is checked.

Comment: If you'd like to post the project (e.g. on github or even thru a dropbox link), I'll look at it and tell you what the problem is.

Comment: How about the stack view? It's also inside a stack view. That would need to have its "user interaction enabled" checked as well.

Comment: @matt https://www.dropbox.com/s/kowbjffo0gdro2f/TestApp.zip?dl=0

Comment: @matt checked that as well. The `UIImage` is already working so I'm sure its checked for the stack view as well.

Comment: Thanks, that was an easy one. See my revised answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the Rating Control has no width / height constraints. Therefore, being inside a stack view, its width and height are reduced to zero. Therefore the button ends up outside the Rating Control (because the latter has zero size; everything is outside it). A subview outside its superview is non-interactive.

Just give the rating control a width constraint and a height constraint and all will be well.

You could easily have detected this by giving the rating control, temporarily, some background color. You would then have seen instantly when running the app that the rating control was missing from the layout.

Comment: Thanks! Because I'm new I had no idea this would happen. The tutorials are a bit outdated as well so maybe that's the reason it wasn't working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's easy to get caught by this because a view outside its superview is untouchable _but visible_, which is very misleading.